# Table as member variable seems to be always nil

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm new to lua and I'm trying to understand their OOP approach. I have this `WebServerClient` object which receives the socket from a client that connects to a webserver:

```
WebServerClient = {}
local WebServerClient_mt = { __index = WebServerClient }

function WebServerClient:Create(socket)
    local self = setmetatable({
        socket = socket,
        buffer = "test",
        header = {},
    }, WebServerClient_mt)
    socket:on("receive", function(socket, data)
        print(self.buffer)
        self.header:insert(data) -- PANIC happens on this line!
        self:onData(data)
    end)
    return self
end
```

The problem is that, once the client sends some data, I get the error:

> PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (WebServerClient.lua:20: attempt to call method 'insert' (a nil value))

So, it seems like `self.header` is `nil`, while I think it should be a valid table. Before the panic, `test` is printed to the console, so I'm pretty sure `self` is initiated correctly. (`data` is not `nil` as I can print it).

I'm using Lua 5.1.

Anyone knows what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.header` is not the `nil` value in question. The `nil` value is `self.header:insert`. `header` is a table, but it's an *empty table*. Therefore, `header.insert` is `nil`.

If you were trying to call the Lua standard function `table.insert`, you can't call that through the actual table. You have to call it like this `table.insert(tbl, value)`, where `tbl` is the table you want to insert.

Tables aren't like strings, where you can call functions from the `string` library through metamethods.

Comment: ah, I understand. As an experiment, I initialized `header` like this: `header = setmetatable({}, { __index = table }),`, then I can call it like `self.header:insert(data)`, or do you think this is a bad idea?

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: That's a *terrible* idea. Just call the function the right way.

Comment: @Nicol I understand it's a bad idea, but out of pure curiosity, how much efficiency loss is there?

Comment: @warspyking According to a small benchmark made by a friend it seems on a million iterations it can be almost 0.1 seconds on lua 5.3 - http://i.imgur.com/tyn6T1B.png